# I have looked for the implementation of the MPI function Scatterv, but I found anything that could help in writing my own function

Tags: c++, mpi

I have a vector of size the number of processors, that has to be scattered to all processors.
I have written (I think in the right way) all the accessory vectors and array that are required for the call to `MPI::COMM_WORLD.Scatterv`. The programs compiles, but once run it says that an address was not mapped.

I will write here only the part of the code that is involved in the Scatterv function.

The code is:

```
std::vector<int> double_gid_m(num_gids);
if (my_id == 0) {
    ...here the values of double_gid_m for each processors are defined
}

std::vector<int> vect_double_gid_size_processors(num_processors);
for (int i=0;i<num_processors;i++) {
    ...in this for loop I define for each vect_double_gid_size_processors[i]
    the amount of data that should be assigned to each processor, with:
    vect_double_gid_size_processors[i]=amount_of_data_for_each_processor[i];
}
```

Afterwards, I define the displacement of assignments for each processors using `vect_double_gid_size_processors`, the amount of data for each processor:

```
int double_gid_size_displacement[num_processors]; 

if (my_id == 0) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_processors; i++) {
    double_gid_size_displacement[i] = sum;
    sum += vect_double_gid_size_processors[i];
    }
}
```

Finally, I call the MPI::COMM_WORLD.Scatterv

```
MPI::COMM_WORLD.Scatterv(&double_gid_m[0], &vect_double_gid_size_processors[0], 
    &double_gid_size_displacement[0], MPI::INT, &double_gid_m[0], 
    vect_double_gid_size_processors[my_id], MPI::INT, 0);
```

I have tried to change some input arguments, such as passing a vector or an array insteand of its address of first element, but in this case the compiler did not work, and gave me this kind of function as the one to be used. I mean with addresses of vectors or array and not the vector or array itself.

Could anyone help me in understanding why the compilation is good, but the run fails with a "Signal: Segmentation fault" and "Signal code: Address not mapped"?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Distilling the problem down to just the essential lines of code is a good start, but it will be a lot easier for people here to answer your question if you include a [self contained example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as described in the [ask] page; then potential responders can tell exactly what's going on.

Comment: For instance, it _looks_ like you're trying to do an in-place scatterv without passing MPI_IN_PLACE as the receive buffer on rank 0, but it'd be easier to know that for sure with a small working code example.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in the call to scatterv.

The call must use different vectors for input and output. In the code above I was using the same vector:

```
double_gid_m
```

Now I defined a new vector gid.m, and everything is going well (... however the code is giving errors in subsequent parts!!!). The code is now:

```
gid_m.resize(2*total_half_gid_size);

MPI::COMM_WORLD.Scatterv(&double_gid_m[0], &vect_double_gid_size_processors[0], &double_gid_size_displacement[0], MPI::INT, &gid_m[0], vect_double_gid_size_processors[my_id], MPI::INT, 0);
```